# git - github reflecting ignored change

Tags: git, github

I have a pull request that has some files I don't want to merge. The thing is, these files are listed in the .gitignore file. both in the base branch and the target branch, they were never ignored, why is github showing them on the PR

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file may be added accidentally. You can always [checkout the pull request locally](https://gist.github.com/piscisaureus/3342247) and make changes to it yourself.

When there are many files that are to be deleted you should use [this](http://www.lemoda.net/git/rm-gitignore-files/) to enforce your `.gitignore`.

Comment: Hi, this is not the only ignored file that has changes, there are many, I'm trying to avoid having to modify them one by one

Comment: Edited my answer. You can still checkout the branch and enforce your gitignore with a new commit. These files might be added accidentally forcing them to be added. IDEs sometimes help to make mistakes :-)

Comment: I ended up deleting all those files that were supposed to be ignored, then I commited and pushed those. and everything got fixed